# MongoDB performance on finding documents with key in a range of values

Tags: c++, mongodb, performance, nosql

Let's say the database 'testdb' has collection 'testcollection'. In this collection, there is a key 'testfield'. **This collection holds billions of documents**.

Finding the exact value of key 'testfield' can be done very fast, even those are billions of documents, coz the index is based on radix tree (possibly?).

```
model.find({
  testfield: "some-value"
})
```

However, when finding in a range of values, is it still fast against these billions of documents?

```
model.find({
  testfield:{
    $gte: "some-lower-value",
    $lte: "some-upper-value"
  }
})
```

Comment: All depends on the exact key-index sorting. Which in turn depends on settings and configurations when constructing the database (can be changed after the fact too). If it's a sorted list of `testfield` values, then it should be relatively quick [assuming upper and lower limits are relatively close, obviously if you have a wide range, a wide part of the db gets sent your way, and that could take some time]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mats Peterson in the comment below the question:

> All depends on the exact key-index sorting. Which in turn depends on
>   settings and configurations when constructing the database (can be
>   changed after the fact too). If it's a sorted list of testfield
>   values, then it should be relatively quick [assuming upper and lower
>   limits are relatively close, obviously if you have a wide range, a
>   wide part of the db gets sent your way, and that could take some time]

The time for finding a range is fast too, but based on the range of values.

The lower value and upper value can be found immediately in ~log(N) just like finding the exact value. As index should be a list of sorted values of the key, the output time depends on the loop to extract all entries from the lower value to upper value.